# How to get carrier_account number in goshippo

Tags: node.js, api, shippo

**How to get carrier_account  number in goshippo **

```
shippo.transaction.create({
    "shipment": shipment,
    "servicelevel_token": "ups_ground",
    "carrier_account": "558c84bbc25a4f609f9ba02da9791fe4",
    "label_file_type": "png"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this website [link](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference/js#carrier-accounts)
use this method:- shippo.carrieraccount.list();